Collaborate Almost identical Jquery Event Listener scripts to write better code
I'm using an Event Listener in Jquery to increment a field number each time a new row is created in a repeating field.
The code works great and if I repeat the entire script for each repeating field, but using a different ID each time it with give the desired result, Incrementing the number in a field each time a new row is created.
I am a novice but even I know that would be bad practice. Is there a way to re-write the code to allow for listening to all repeating fields (I'm expecting to limit the form to 20 possible repeaters) then have it increment the correct field by ID each time, without me simply repeating the same snippet for each field ID?



<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", updateRepeatCountFields );
jQuery(document).on('frmAfterAddRow', updateRepeatCountFields );
jQuery(document).on('frmAfterRemoveRow', updateRepeatCountFields );

function updateRepeatCountFields(){
var countFields = document.querySelectorAll( '.frm_field_194_container input');
    for ( var i = 0, len=countFields.length; i<len; i++ ) {
        countFields[i].value = i+1;
    }
}
</script>




It's not clear what the goal is here - could you please amend the description to provide more details about what you're trying to achieve. The single image alone is not providing any useful context. It may be more beneficial if you could also add the HTML to create a working example
